# Controlling Drawer using state In ShadCN and NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, shadcnui

I have the following shadcn drawer component implemented in the following manner:

```
              <Drawer
                open={showCustomizationDrawer}
                onOpenChange={setShowCustomizationDrawer}>
                <DrawerTrigger
                  className="absolute right-[15%] bottom-[5px]"
                  asChild>
                  <Button className="absolute right-[15%] bottom-[5px]">
                    Add
                  </Button>
                </DrawerTrigger>
                <DrawerContent>
                  ...
                </DrawerContent>
              </Drawer>
```

As you can see the opening of the drawer is controlled by the `showCustomizationDrawer` state which takes boolean values. All works as expected when i use the drawer trigger, opens and closes as expected. But now outside of this drawer i have a button with the following onClick:

```
              onClick={() => {
                setShowCustomizationDrawer(true);
              }}
```

I expect the drawer to open when i click this button, since im changing the state of the `showCustomizationDrawer` state. There are no errors on the console either.

Comment: Can you provide reproduction?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelbaset I can share the link to the repo if thats okay: 
https://github.com/vedant-shah/crums

its a nextjs project, but it has backend, hence it may not work as expected for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the repo in the comments is not a real reproduction. Reproduce the issue is to start a new project that doesn't have anything else but the issue being described.

I tried to reproduce it simply and it works fine:

```js
"use client";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Drawer, DrawerContent, DrawerTrigger } from "@/components/ui/drawer";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Page() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  console.log("isOpen", isOpen);

  return (
    <Drawer open={isOpen} onOpenChange={setIsOpen}>
      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Another Button</Button>

      <DrawerTrigger>Open Drawer</DrawerTrigger>
      <DrawerContent>Drawer Content</DrawerContent>
    </Drawer>
  );
}
```

At the previous snippet both of `<DrawerTrigger>` and `<Button>` are working as expected and opening the drawer.

In your case maybe the button sets the state as expected but the other conditions does not presend:

```js
dish.availableCustomizations &&
  items.filter((item) => item._id === dish._id).length === 0 && 
    <Drawer
      // ...
```

Try to `console.log` all `showCustomizationDrawer` and the other conditions to figure where is the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, kind sir, and forgive me for my wrong doing. As you mentioned, I have made a screen recording of the various state changes for `showCustomizationDrawer`. The states are changing as expected but the drawer is not opening.

The video link can be found here: https://imgur.com/a/Ru56Gdc

Comment: console log these as well `dish.availableCustomizations &&
  items.filter((item) => item._id === dish._id).length === 0`

Comment: Oh, my goodness. I have made a rookie mistake. This shouldn't be happening at this stage. Do know that I appreciate and am grateful for your continued support and efforts.  I will take this post down. Thank you again!

Comment: Don't delete it. Keep it there for anyone facing similar issue